# WCF two-way call: unexpected recursion

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, recursion, two-way

Our Winforms module is a WCF client and while processing WM_PAINT it calls two-way method of a WCF service. I was expecting it to wait for a reply; however a recursion occurs, resulting in a nested WM_PAINT, with all sorts of problems following that.
Now I realise that WM_PAINT handler is probably not the best place for calls across the wire, but how is the above behavior possible in the first place? **Isn’t the WCF client thread supposed to block while waiting for a reply to a two-way call?**
The UI module makes use of two third party libraries, so I’m unsure who's to blame for what’s happening. Calling across the wire in WM_PAINT is no good IMHO but it should not have caused a recursion on its own.
Here’s the stack:

```
<Our code – recursion!>
System.dll!System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertToString(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
SmartPropertyGrid.dll!VisualHint.SmartPropertyGrid.PropertyValue.ConvertValueToDisplayedString(object value)
SmartPropertyGrid.dll!VisualHint.SmartPropertyGrid.PropertyValueIndirect.HasMultipleTexts(out string text, out bool textIsExceptionText)
SmartPropertyGrid.dll!VisualHint.SmartPropertyGrid.PropertyValue.HasMultipleTexts()
SmartPropertyGrid.dll!VisualHint.SmartPropertyGrid.Property.Draw(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics, System.Drawing.Rectangle itemRect, VisualHint.SmartPropertyGrid.PropertyVisibleDeepEnumerator enumSelf)
SmartPropertyGrid.dll!A.c84db8915b8e0ce02a23aa50484601540.OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e, short layer)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
SmartPropertyGrid.dll!A.c84db8915b8e0ce02a23aa50484601540.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)
[Native to Managed Transition]
[Managed to Native Transition]
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, long millisecondsTimeout, bool hasThreadAffinity, bool exitContext)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(System.TimeSpan timeout, bool exitContext)
System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll!System.Runtime.TimeoutHelper.WaitOne(System.Threading.WaitHandle waitHandle, System.TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.SyncDuplexRequest.WaitForReply(System.TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.Request(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message, System.TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(string action, bool oneway, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime operation, object[] ins, object[] outs, System.TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMethodCallMessage methodCall, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage message)
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(ref System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.MessageData msgData, int type)
[Native to Managed Transition]
[Managed to Native Transition]
[Managed to Native Transition]  
<Our code>
```

Comment: You call a WCF service in a Paint Message? omg why

Comment: Anyway, this is all very strange to say the least and there is not enough information here to help you. you will need to do some forensic debugging and work out the true nature of what you are doing

Comment: @TheGeneral: It's a legacy code, I'm going to improve/refactor it.

Answer (score 0):

**If you update the question with you code, we can try to help with solution.**

The processing of WM_PAINT message should be super fast. Any other computation than the directyl related to painting should be done elsewhere (in another thread). And the important think - the WM_PAINT can be received event when control/form is not shown in the screen. Something else can call it for getting "screenshot" of your control/form.

Comment: I believe we all agree that doing anything "heavy" in WM_PAINT is bad, full stop.
The real puzzle though is why the recursion occurs, whereas a two-way call should have blocked the thread.

Comment: @alexk Without the source code is nearly impossible say anything more usefull.